# Capture sound from headphones in OpenAL

Tags: c++, capture, recording, openal

I want to record sound from headphones with OpenAL. I know how to record microphone, I know how to save a data into .wav file. But I can't find a way to record a headphones.

I have a name of a headphones device, but when I pass it to ***alcCaptureOpenDevice()*** this function returns NULL and the only way to make this function return not NULL is to pass a default capture device(which is a microphone). Maybe I understand something wrong about this function.

So my question is there any way to record a sound from headphones in OpenAL?

Comment: Headphones are output devices. You normally can't "reverse" them and use them as microphones. If what you actually want to do is to capture the sound output from your computer, that's probably possible, but you need to get to it before it reaches an output port.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I thought so, but is there a way to capture output device then with openal?

Comment: The approach depends on wether you are trying to capture system audio or audio you have generated. Could you clarify a little more on what audio you want to capture or what you want to do with it?